# how to automitcally create point of sale session while creating new company in oddo 12?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

create override in create company to show this company in point of sell :

```
class ResCompany(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.company'

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        Self.env['pos.config'].create()

        return super(res.company, self).create(vals)
```

Comment: What is the exact question? Please be more elaborate on the problem statement and add examples or error details if any.

Comment: I make the question more clear